# density distribution and bar plot from x and y data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data set in a pandas dataframe:

```
x = df_data.iloc[:,0].values
y = df_data.iloc[:,1].values
```

The following data is in x and y, respectively:

```
x = 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36
y = 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000
```

y represents the counts (how often each x value exists).

I now want to make a bar plot with the density distribution line. I'm open to using seaborn or matplotlib, but couldn't find a way to enter x and y data separately and to obtain the bar plot plus the density plot.

I've tried this:

```
x = [30,31,32,33,34,35,36]
y = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]
##
sns.distplot(x, hist=True, kde=True,
    bins=int(150/150), color='darkblue',
    hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
    kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
plt.show()
```

but didn't get what I wanted.

I would like to have something like below (just for my data)

[image]

(i got this image from: https://towardsdatascience.com/histograms-and-density-plots-in-python-f6bda88f5ac0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, note that `distplot` has been depreciated in Seaborn 0.11. The extended and improved versions are now called `histplot` (histogram with optional kde ), `kdeplot` (for just a kde) and `displot` (creates subplots).

The optional `weights=` parameter sets weights for each of the `x` values. `discrete=True` is needed to have a bar for each `x` value. The `cut` parameter of the kde controls how far the curve is drawn outside the data points.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
y = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]

sns.histplot(x=x, weights=y, discrete=True,
             color='darkblue', edgecolor='black',
             kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 2}, line_kws={'linewidth': 4})
plt.show()
```

[image: histplot with weights]

Note that in case the underlying data is continuous, you'd get a much correcter plot by providing the original data.

To change the color of the kde line, an obvious idea would be to use `line_kws={'color': 'red'}`, but this doesn't work in the current seaborn version (0.11.1).

However, you can draw a `histplot` and `kdeplot` separately. In order to have matching y-axes, the `histplot` needs `stat='density'` (the default is `'count'`).

```py
ax = sns.histplot(x=x, weights=y, discrete=True, alpha=0.5,
                  color='darkblue', edgecolor='black', stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(x=x, weights=y, color='crimson', cut=2, linewidth=4, ax=ax)
```

Another approach is to change the color of the line afterwards, which works independently of the chosen `stat=`.

```py
ax = sns.histplot(x=x, weights=y, discrete=True,
             color='darkblue', edgecolor='black',
             kde=True, kde_kws={'cut': 2}, line_kws={'linewidth': 4})
ax.lines[0].set_color('crimson')
```

[image: sns.histplot with changed line color]

Here is an example how a histogram for one dataset can be combined with a kde curve of another dataset:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
import seaborn as sns

x = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
y = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]
x2 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
y2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]

ax = sns.histplot(x=x2, weights=y2, discrete=True, alpha=0.5,
                  color='darkblue', edgecolor='black', stat='density')
sns.kdeplot(x=x, weights=y, color='crimson', cut=2, linewidth=4, ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: combining a histplot with a kdeplot of a different dataset]

Comment: great. is there a possibility to now change the color of the blue line to red but keep the color of the histogram as blue?

Comment: Thank you! Last question: if I now wanted to plot this red line, for the data above in a figure without the histogram, but instead add the histogram of another set of data to the figure instead i.e.: histogram for x2 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] and y2 = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000], plus red line for x = [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
y = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 3000, 2000, 1000]. Is this possible?

Comment: You'll need `histplot` without kde but with `stat='density'` and then a separate `kdeplot`.  Note that without `stat='density'` histograms for both datasets would have quite a different scale.